# Can't use value passed via PHP in conditional construct

Tags: php

I'm having this problem for 4 hours now and can't seem to find a way to solve it. I'm passing a boolean value ($b1) which is the result of include.php to my script, and then using a simple condition on it.

The conditioning doesn't work as I am getting 'nok' for both 1 and 0. Tried using another variable = intval (passed value) but that doesn't seem to work either.

```
<?php    
ob_start();
include ('include.php');    
$b1 = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $b1;
if($b1==1) echo "ok";
if ($b1==0) echo "nok";
?>
```

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What is $b1 when you echo it before the if ? checking for boolean should be `if($b1)` for true and `if(!$b1)` for false

Comment: please try var_dump($b1) and post the output

Comment: This produces "1nok" as output. The include.php outputs "1".

Comment: tried vardump, outputs: "string(131) " 1" nok". But if there is a blank space to the left wouldn't intval($b1) have had it removed and return the int value of the string?

Comment: does your `include.php` really output "1" ?

Comment: string(129) "1" after using preg_replace and str_replace. The conditioning still doesn't work.

Comment: What's in `include.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter unless you are not echoing something. For example, if you will run this code, it will work:

```
<?php    
ob_start();
//include ('include.php');    
echo 1;
$b1 = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $b1;
if($b1==1) echo "ok";
if ($b1==0) echo "nok";
?>
```

The reason is that $b1 will contain the output buffer value only. So you need to echo a value either in include.php or before assigning ob_get_contents() to $b1.

You can read further from this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php